# Magento session reset on every request

Tags: magento, session

I have a very critical issue with my Magento store. The session gets reset on every HTTP request, for example if I refresh the homepage it creates a new session.

Initially I thought it was from the php.ini settings but I set session.cookie_lifetime = 86400 ni my php.ini file and from magento backend as ewll. Then I also moved the session from files to db to try and resolve the problem but it keeps creating new sessions on every request. As a result of this I can't add any items to the cart or do anything else because my session gets destroyed every time.

Comment: where did you get the issue in local or live sever?

Comment: on live server, running CentOS and Nginx.

Comment: try to set default theme and disable all custom modules. Maybe some module instantiate new session.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by enabling "Use SID on Frontend" in 'system->web->session validation settings'.

Hope the following will helps you.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/385/cart-dropping-all-items-cart-session-clears

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and located it in this file:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
```

In order to fix it more elegantly one should override the specified file in the local code pool insted of modifying the core directly. Like below:

```
app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
```

Also for the above to work php.ini setting `session.cookie_secure` must be commented or set to 0.

Comment: or you also can try to empty cookie_domain value (in system/configuration, or if you can't access there - fix it in core_config_data)

Comment: what was the code you changed to solve the issue,if it was in that class

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check your php.ini

I had a similar problem and noticed that the .ini was trying to set a different save path for the sessions then Magento.

In short edit php.ini and comment out the save_path and cookie_secure:

```
;session.save_path =
;session.cookie_secure =
```

I'm sure there is a way in Magento to set the secure cookie param, as I would not want to suggest anything that maybe a security risk.

Then restart php or apache